# Float comparison issues in Perl

Tags: perl, floating-point, comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix this Perl code so that 1.1 + 2.2 == 3.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916314/how-do-i-fix-this-perl-code-so-that-1-1-2-2-3-3)

I'm working on a Perl script that compares strings representing gene models and prints out a summary of the comparison. If the gene models match perfectly, I print out a very terse summary, but if they are different, the summary is quite verbose.

The script looks at the value of a variable to determine whether it should do the terse or verbose summary--if the variable is equal to 1, it should print the terse summary; otherwise, it should print the verbose summary.

Since the value is numeric (a float), I've been using the `==` operator to do the comparison.

```
if($stats->{overall_simple_matching_coefficient} == 1)
{
  print "Gene structures match perfectly!\n";
}
```

This worked correctly for all of my tests and even for most of the new cases I am running now, but I found a weird case where the value was equal to 1 but the above comparison failed. I have not been able to figure out why the comparison failed, and stranger yet, when I changed the `==` operator to the `eq` operator, it seemed to work fine.

I thought the `==` was for numerical comparison and `eq` was for string comparison. Am I missing something here?

Update: If I print out the value right before the comparison...

```
printf("Test: '%f', '%d', '%s'\n", $stats->{overall_simple_matching_coefficient}, $stats->{overall_simple_matching_coefficient}, $stats->{overall_simple_matching_coefficient});
```

...I get this.

```
Test: '1.000000', '0', '1'
```

Comment: What do you get if you print the value of `$stats->{overall_simple_matching_coefficient}` just before the comparison?

Comment: Oh, I was actually doing that earlier. Thanks, I'll put that up.

Comment: Not sure about perl, don't use it that much, but in bash at least `==` is for strings and `-eq` is for numerics...

Comment: See my answer below.  Try printf with more decimal places and I'm pretty sure you'll see the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first thing any computer language teacher should teach you about any computer language is that [YOU CANNOT COMPARE FLOATS FOR EQUALIT](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)Y.  This is true of any language.  Floating point arithmetic is not exact, and two floats that look like they're the same will be different in the insignificant digits somewhere where you can't see it.  Instead, you can only compare that they are *close* to each other - like

```
if (abs(stats->{overall_simple_matching_coefficient)-1) < 0.0001)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The hard part for me was determining the tolerance/specificity I need, because for long genes, a value of 0.9999 could be valid and distinct from a value of 1.0000. After I though a bit more about it, though, the tolerance required is just a function of the gene's length (which is an integer value). If a gene has a length of 100, then the tolerance needed is .01. If it had a length of 1000, I need .001, and so forth.

Comment: But this still doesn't answer my question about `==` vs `eq`. Why did `eq` work when `==` didn't?

Comment: `eq` compares as strings - if converting the float to a string drops the insignificant digits, `eq` will compare them equal.  But that's a bad thing to rely on - far better is to know what sort of tolerance you need and compare it with that tolerance.

Comment: the default precision for stringification is just slightly less than the maximum precision of the float type used.  for 64-bit floats, for instance, you get 53 bits of mantissa, but they stringify to 15 digits (= ~49.8 bits), so each stringified number  represents a number of distinct numeric values.

Answer (score 3):

What do you get if you print the value of `$stats->{overall_simple_matching_coefficient}` just before the comparison?  If it's `1`, try printf with a format of `"%20.10f"`.  I strongly suspect you have some rounding error (less then 1e-6) accumulated in the variable and it's not comparing equal numerically.  However when converted to string, since the error is right of the 6th decimal place, and the default string format is to six places, it compares equal.

Comment: Thanks for helping me visualize the problem!